# similar to __asm int 3 in Max OS X/ Xcode?

Tags: xcode, debugging, macos

When using visual studio to develop c++ applications, I used to write __asm int 3; and then build the application. When the application is executed, if the code path that has "__asm int 3" is encountered Visual Studio Debugger used to get lauched and I could debug the problems.

Is there any similar approach when developing using Xcode on Mac OS X?

Thanks a lot.

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Debugger() is the gcc equivalent

Comment: That only works if the app is launched under Xcode.  There's no mechanism for a Mac OS X application to, under exceptional conditions, go and launch the IDE and get itself attached to the debugger as the OP describes.